# Putting content in scroll view using storyboard that is longer than length of screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

How do I make my UIScrollview big enough in storyboard so that I can adda all the content I need to it? The amount of content I am adding is longer vertically than an iPhone screen, but storyboard will not let me detach the scroll view from the view controller so that I can extend it vertically and add all my required content.

How do I extend the scrollview vertically in storyboard so that I can add all the content I need to add to it?

Rephrasing: I want to put a lot of things in my scrollview, using interface builder, The interface builder iPhone rectangles do not allow me to add things below the end of the virtual screen, I am using a scroll view because I need to add things below the end of a regular iPhone screen. For example, in Android development, when you run out of vertical space on a scroll view in the layout.xml, the scroll view gets longer so yo can add more things, is there a way to do a similar thing in storyboard?

Comment: Did you try changing view controller's simulated size to "freeform" ?

Comment: I did, but none of the content I put on the scroll view when I make it freeform shows up when I run the app on the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in the Xcode 10 storyboard.  I was able to solve the problem by selecting the ViewController in Storyboard, and then selecting the Size Inspector.  It shows the Simulated Size...

I changed the Simulated Size to Freeform, and then changed the Height to 1000 (or whatever size you need it to be) to elongate the View Controller displayed in the Storyboard.

Don't know about runtime issues.  I'm assuming I might need to change the Simulated Size back to Fixed with the original size.

Answer (score 0):

@AlexFritz: This is happening because you're not setting contentSize of the scrollView. When you are done putting your subviews in UIScrollView you can put the UIViewController's frame back to its original size. And use this following screen shot to set you ScrollView's contentSize.

[image: Set ScrollView's Content Size]

Keep in mind to select the scrollview before setting this property from interface builder.

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I may not have communicated my question effectively. This is not something that is happening at runtime, I am saying that the scroll view in Storyboard is not big enough vertically for me to fit everything I need to fit on there without making it really small, I need more vertical real estate on my scroll view in storyboard. I have not even gotten to worrying about run time yet because I am not able to properly design my scrollview.

Comment: There are two problems i see here.. Detaching UIScrollView from UIViewController, this is caused because of Springs-n-Struts or Auto-Layout-Constraints.
For UIScrollView to be enlarged, EDUsta is right. Make your UIViewController freeform, increase its height which will increase the height of UIScrollView. Or even if not increased, you can increase the height of UIScrollView from Size Inspector and put your subviews in UIScrollView.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to make your scrollview size big, Keep your scroll view Size as it is with repect to the view, Only add a label as a subview to the ScrollView then make its height big enough to contain all your text and just set the content offset of the scrollview big enough to accommodate the label

Comment: I am trying to add a lot of content, imageviews, and textviews to this scroll view.

Comment: then I would suggest Instead of a scrollview you add these to your scrollview as subview, and set the content offset accordingly so that, all the elements are visible when you scroll

Comment: I need to position things in exact places on the scroll view, to do that I need to be able to see all the content on the scroll view. There is not way I can just make the scroll view longer like in Android when you run out of vertical space?

Comment: you don't need to do that, Assign an appropriate frame to the UIElements, and UI can run and check in simulator, if they are properly placed or not

Comment: so you are saying I should add all my elements in the code instead of in the interface builder?

Comment: that would work too, but you can also set the frame in your storyboard to the UI elements